# Combining Regex multiple different alphabetical chars

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate a input field with the following chars:
a-z A-Z () - '(space)' but also special alphabetical characters from my language:
ș ț ă Ă etc.

I have 2 regex expressions:

```
var diacritice = /^[a-zA-Z\)\(-]+$/g;
var caractere = /[^\x00-\x7F]+$/g;
```

How do I combine those into one ? As I've tried different ways could not get there.

In the end it has to be something like this

```
$.validator.addMethod("charsonly", function(value, element) {

    var diacritice = /^[a-zA-Z\)\(-]+$/g;
    var caractere = /[^\x00-\x7F]+$/g;

    return this.optional(element) || (regex).test(value);
  }, "Vă rugăm să folosiți doar caractere alfabetice");
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around the problem of not being able to directly combine a positive and negative character class, you could use both classes in an alternation:

```
var combined = /^(?:[a-zA-Z\)\(-]|[^\x00-\x7F])+$/g;
```

Comment: I did try alternation, however mine didn't work as it was missing ?:() so, perfect ! Thank you.